# Applying a tint to an image to make the image grayscale in Java?

Tags: java, colors

I was wondering whether or not you could apply a tint to a colored image to make a black and white version of that image. For example, having a landscape, applying a tint, and the new photo being only black and white. I'm dealing with an image that I cannot directly change the RGB pixel values for, which is why my only option is to overlay something on top of it. I attempted some Google searches, but to no avail, and unfortunately, I'm not an expert in color theory.

In essence, I'm looking for something that would accomplish this for any color:

COLOR + MAGIC VALUE = GRAY-SCALED (desaturated) COLOR

To be clear, 'magic value' is the color that I hope exists. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

There is no magic colour value that will do this for you.

**The long version**

Let's assume that the grayscale value for a pixel is equivalent to the average values of R, G and B.

If we represent the colour of a pixel as {R,G,B} and let's say you have a 2x2 image:

```
{10,20,30} {30,50,70}
{90,70,80} {90,130,110}
```

.. and you want to convert this to:

```
{20,20,20} {50,50,50}
{80,80,80} {110,110,110}
```

The magic values would need to be:

```
{10,0,-10} {20,0,-20}
{-10,10,0} {20,-10,0}
```

As shown, this magic colour value has to be different for each pixel (but can be calculated from the original image).